# If and switch JS

Tags: javascript

I set few conditions on if/else but it only working on first condition, I used another way switch and found it completely worked, how do I fixed it?

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  let contentall = document.getElementById(`content${i}`)
  contentall.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (xhr.onreadystatechange = okgo) {
          let ibg3 = document.querySelectorAll('.ibg3 img')
          let text2 = document.querySelectorAll('.text2')
          let text4 = document.querySelectorAll('.text4')
          let ibg4 = document.querySelectorAll('.ibg4')
          let arr = [ibg3, ibg4, text2, text4]
          if (e.target !== text2[i - 1] || text4[i - 1] || ibg3[i - 1] || ibg4[i - 1]) {
            console.log("no match")
          } else {
            letgotall(i - 1)
            return
          }

          switch (e.target) {
            case ibg3[i - 1]:
              letgotall(i - 1)
              break;
            case text2[i - 1]:
              letgotall(i - 1)
              break;
            case text4[i - 1]:
              letgotall(i - 1)
              break;
            case ibg4[i - 1]:
              letgotall(i - 1)
              break;
            default:
              console.log("failure")
          }
        }
```

Comment: Kindly remove any expletives from your code before posting. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry for that, done.

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. As a side effect, doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely that you will get people to up-vote your posts and makes it more likely that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't matter which style your choose (although, IMO, some are more appropriate for JavaScript than others). But, pick one and use it consistently for all code in a single project.

Comment: Thanks for reminder, I'm wondering why I got so much down-vote,  it's my first time knew what's indenting style, thanks again.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because your condition is wrong, right way is

```
if(e.target !== text2[i-1] || e.target !== text4[i-1])
```

or if you don want to repeat e.target you can use

```
if (!Set(text2[i-1], text4[i-1]).has(e.target)) console.log("Jesus Christ")
```